# If $R$ is a subring of a field $F$, then the ring of fractions is embedded in $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, fractions, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a subring of a field $F$ and $D$ a multiplicative **semigroup** of $R$. I need to prove that the ring of fractions $D^{-1}R$ is embedded in $F$.

To do so, I began by supposing that $R$ is such a subring of $F$ and $D$ a multiplicative semigroup of $R$. Then, I noted that since the subring of a field is an integral domain, here $R$ is an integral domain.

Next, I have a result that tells me that if $R$ is a commutative ring and $D$ is a nonempty multiplicative subgroup of $R$, then the following is true:

- (a) The map $\phi: R \to D^{-1}R$ defined by 
  $$ \phi(x) = \frac{xy}{y}\, \text{for some}\, y \in D$$
  is a ring homomorphism.
- (b) If $0 \notin D$ and $D$ has no zero divisors then $\phi$ is a monomorphism.
- (c) The image $\phi(x)$ of every element $x \in D$ is invertible; i.e., $\phi(D) \subseteq U(D^{-1}R)$.
- (d) If $R$ has the identity and $D \subseteq U(R)$ then $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

By this, then, I have that for $\phi: R \to D^{-1}R$, $\phi(x) = \frac{xy}{y}$ for some $y \in D$ is a monomorphism.

Now, consider $f:R \to F$, and let $f$ be a homomorphism such that $f(D) \subseteq U(F) = F \setminus \{0 \}$.

Then, by the universal property of rings of fractions, $\exists$ a unique homormophism $\overline{f}: D^{-1}R \to F$ such that the following diagram is commutative:

[image]

Now, in order to prove that the ring $D^{-1}R$ is embedded in $F$, I need to prove that $\overline{f}$ is a monomorphism, but I am at a loss to see how I can do that.

If somebody could please let me know how to proceed from here, I would be very thankful – I've been thinking about this for a while and nothing has come to me.
I also need to show that the field $F$ is unique up to isomorphism. If you could help with that as well, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: For integral domains If $R \subseteq S$ then $Frac(R) \subseteq Frac(S)$. Here $F = Frac(F)$

Comment: @reuns are you saying that here, $S = F$?

Comment: @ALannister Yes. $S=F$.

Comment: @M.Lobo I think I need to prove this though using some sort of injective mapping.

Comment: For integral domain $Frac(R) = \{\frac{u}{v}, u \in R, v \in R^*\}$ (with the addition, multiplication and equality defined obviously). It is obvious that $R \subseteq S \implies Frac(R) \subseteq Frac(S)$

Comment: The more general setting is that if $\varphi : R \to S$ is a ring morphism between integral domains, then $\varphi$ extends to a field morphism $Frac(R) \to Frac(S), \varphi(\frac{u}{v}) =\frac{\varphi(u)}{\varphi(v)}$ iff $ker(\varphi) = \{0\}$.

Comment: @reuns another thing I noticed as I sat here looking at this: since $R$ is an integral domain, $D^{-1}R$ is a field. You're referring to the universal property here, right?

Comment: Everything is obvious for integral domains. The universal property is useful for other rings, where the different possible localizations is less obvious. Also $D$ is not a subgroup but a multiplicatively closed set (try with $R = \mathbb{Z}$) and $D^{-1}R$ is a field (ie. $Frac(R)$) only when $R^* \subseteq R^\times D$

Comment: If $D$ is a group then $D \subseteq R^\times $ and $D^{-1} R = R$

Comment: @reuns I realize I said something incorrect a while ago, and so you're most certainly right that $D^{-1}R$ is not a field. It is an integral domain though. So, I'm wondering that if in your ring morphism $\varphi$ your $R$ is doing the job of $D^{-1}R$ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds if and only if $0\notin D$, which I'll assume from now on.

The universal property already gives you a homomorphism
$$
f\colon D^{-1}R\to F
$$
defined by
$$
f(x/d)=xd^{-1}
$$
The reason is that, for the embedding $R\to F$, every element of $D$ is invertible. You need to show this homomorphism is injective.

If $f(x/d)=0$, then $xd^{-1}=0$, so $x=0$ and therefore $x/d=0$.

Comment: I'm working on showing that the homomorphism is injective right now. How are you able to conclude that $xd^{-1} = 0$ implies that $x=0$? Because it's an element of a field?

Comment: also, then when you have that $x=0$, what specifically allows you to conclude that $x/d = 0$? I apologize if these are silly questions, but I just want to make sure I understand everything.

Comment: @ALannister If $xd^{-1}=0$ in $F$, just multiply both sides by $d$. Moreover $0/d=0/1$ in $D^{-1}R$, just apply the definition.

Comment: let's say I was expressing elements of $D^{-1}R$ as $[(x,d)]$ instead of as $x/d$ (i.e., as equivalence classes of tuples instead of as fractions), how would I express the zero element there then so that addition of $[(x_{1},y_{1})]$ by zero would make sense? Here, I have defined addition to be given by $[(x_{1},y_{1})] + [(x_{2},y_{2})] = [(x_{1}y_{2} + x_{2}y_{1},y_{1}y_{2})]$

Comment: @ALannister With $x/d$ I denote the same as you are denoting with `$[(x,d)]$. The zero element is obviously $0/1$ or, if you don't assume $1\in D$, $0/d$ for any $d\in D$. Just check it has the required property.

Comment: of course! How silly of me.